# Got a ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead while fiiting my image data into decisiontree classifier

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn import 
from matplotlib import image
import os
features=list()
##this loops are to load images as arrays in to features from the folders on my desktop
for f in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\Sriram\Desktop\300'):
    if f.endswith('.png'):
        try:

            pass
for f in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\Sriram\Desktop\300n'):
    if f.endswith('.png'):
        try:
            img=image.imread(r'C:\Users\Sriram\Desktop\300n'+f)
            features.append(img)
        except:
            pass
l=[0]
p=[1]
print("hello")
## there are onlt two classes if images each 20 hence i created targets ast list of 40 elements first
##for class 1 and other for 2
targets=l*20+p*20
##thi is where i get error
clf=tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf=clf.fit(features,targets)
```

---

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Sriram/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/ML2.py",
>   line 24, in 
>       clf=clf.fit(features,targets)   File "C:\Users\Sriram\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree_classes.py",
>   line 873, in fit
>       super().fit(   File "C:\Users\Sriram\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree_classes.py",
>   line 149, in fit
>       X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csc")   File "C:\Users\Sriram\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py",
>   line 552, in check_array
>       raise ValueError( ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=[]. Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1)
>   if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it
>   contains a single sample.

I was trying to load some images from my desktop using `matplotlib` .those include only two classes of images and then i want to train a `decisiontreeclassifier` and when I try to access fit method using these 
features I got above error

Answer (score 0):

fit method expect to input shape to be  `(n_samples, n_features)`.If you have a 1D array you need to convert it to 2D array before fit to the model.You can use reshape method as suggested in the error.

```
clf=clf.fit(features.reshape(-1,1),targets)
```